# Allow one view controller to rotate landscape in swift2 xcode7

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iPhone app which device orientation is set to portrait. But there's a view controller that takes picture and I need it to auto rotate when the phone changes its orientation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to enable `Portrait`, `Landscape Left` and `Landscape Right` orientations from project settings.

Then use `supportedInterfaceOrientations` function in your `UIViewController` to tell what orientations are supported in that view controller. App will crash if you try to support `Landscape` mode here without selecting that mode in your project settings.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape]
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, this is the craziness of it. You can't just enable rotation for one view. You have to *disable* rotation for every other view. It's crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly. But if you want to have several previews you can choose Preview then click "+" at the bottom left corner of the preview window to add the second preview and set it to landscape orientation. As far as I know you cannot preview 2 view controllers at the same time. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't give much information in my question. My app only supports portrait mode in all views. But there is a view to take photo , that I want to support both landscape and portrait modes.